# Budget json file not working in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, performance, wordpress-theming, core-web-vitals

I have created a custom WordPress theme for a client who wanted to replace genesis with a bespoke one. Performance and speed are super important for my client and I have been testing the site multiple times to get the core web vitals passed.

However after creating a budget.json file within my custom theme file as suggested [here](https://web.dev/use-lighthouse-for-performance-budgets/) it's not showing the new results in Lighthouse or Pagespeed insights whatsoever.

I also created a theme.json file and added the json there as well which is making no difference.

Grateful for any ideas on this.

Comment: This feels like it would almost certainly be more suitable on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ - is there any actual *programming* involved in this question?

Comment: From the instructions in the link you shared it seems to me that you need to place the budget.json file in the root directory of your website (eg. /public_html) and not inside your theme's folder. Have you tried that already?

Comment: @cabrerahector haha thank you now why didnt I think of that, yep will ftp it up. that makes total sense to me know.